# Is there an architecture in ROS 2 to put “backpressue” on upstream nodes to slow is down?

Tags: ros2, roscpp, publisher, subscribe

**Pipeline description:**

- Node A - Camera Driver Node that publishes images(topic 1) at 30 Hz.
- Node B - Objection detection Node subscribes to images(topic 1) and
  publishes 2D detections(topic 2)
- Node C - Subscribes to images(topic 1) and 2D detections(topic 2) and publishes 3D detections(topic 3)

**Benchmark numbers**

- Node B running on its own(using rosbag data) has been benchmarked to run at 60 Hz.
- Node C running on its own has been benchmarked to run at 1 Hz.

If I setup the the above pipeline together, Node B will run at 30Hz and Node C will at 0.1 Hz.
But Node B running 2D object detection at 30Hz is wasteful. Because Node C cannot consume it at that rate.

I can add a throttling node after Node A to tune(reduce) the rate of topic 1 to a acceptable rate based on my compute limitation.

**Main Question**

But in ROS 2, is there a good way to automatically tune the system mentioned above without using a throttling node?

or

Is there an architecture in ROS 2 to put “backpressue” on upstream nodes to slow is down?

Comment: Define "back pressure"